# Android Handler Interface to start/stop AsyncTask

Tags: android-asynctask, android-handler

I am totally new in the Android world & need help on how to create & add a Handler interface that use to stop & restart the Asynctask every 10Sec. while its active (before screen touch events).

My AsyncTask is used to change the screen background color every 2 Sec. as below. I am using `Button.onClick` to start the AsyncTask & any screen touch event later to stop it.

```
public class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Runasync = true;
        while (Runasync) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                break;
            }
            try {

                    Thread.sleep(2000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        ChangeBackgroudColor();  //Calling Method to change the background color.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Timer & TimerTask](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html) for 10 seconds interval.

Create `Handler` as below in Main Thread.

[image]

Implement functionality for START_ASYNC_TASK message in you handle message Switch - Case and Cancel the existing Asynctask and start a new asynctask here.

[image]

use `mHandler.post()` method in TimerTask to post a message to the UI Thread.

In your activity override